# Modify shared_prefs XML file from adb shell

Tags: adb, shell

My Tolino Vision 4 HD e-book reader has no vi, vim.tiny or any other text editor executable, so to edit files I have to "adb pull" it to my PC, modify it there and "adb push" it back.
This takes too long for quick tinkering. "adb push" also sets new user+group to the file (root:root) instead of the original permissions.

Is there an in-built cli tool to modify application `shared_prefs` XML files while inside `adb shell`? (Add a new property and value, modify existing property's value, delete property)

---

I already patched `adb` to allow root access, so permissions are not a problem. I'm just asking for a convenience tool.

Comment: Sorry but if you expect an answer you should at least name the ebook reader you are talking about. Are you sure it runs on Android? Can you install Android app to it? Have you root access on the device? Please edit your questions and add those deatils.

Comment: By "in-built cli tool", did you mean from the Android device itself? Some custom ROMs provide an in-built Terminal app, but to access other app's internal data (including shared preferences), the device needs to be rooted due to the nature of Android's app sandboxing.